# How can I read a binary file in sections?

Tags: vlang

How can I read a binary file in sections?  (read some, skip forward, read some more, ...)

I tried the `fn (f &File) read_bytes(size int)` function, but was surprised that it always reads from the front.

Do we really need to re-implement the C `File` structure (which `V` also re-implements) to track the current file position?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [File.read_bytes_at](https://modules.vlang.io/os.html#File.read_bytes_at). You need to keep track of the position yourself:

```
import os

path :='v.exe'
size :=1024*256

mut f := os.open(path) or {println(err) return}
for pos := 0;; pos += size {
    arr := f.read_bytes_at(size, pos)
    println(arr.len)
    if arr.len == 0 {break}
}
f.close()
```

For me this gives the following output:

```
262144
262144
262144
262144
186094
0
```

**Update:** in git master I've added a function that can read data into a buffer to avoid allocating on each call:

```
    mut arr := []byte{len: size}
    ...
    nread := f.read_bytes_into(pos, arr) or {
        panic(err)
    }
    if nread == 0 {break}
```